# How populate database records into my table ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

So i go this information and have a empty table name categorytable so i have to have records stored in categoryList for the below code to work. so what do i write in categoryList which is to fetch the record from my category manager and display the data from sql

```
    </table>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var categoryList = [];


        var $courseTableElement = $('#categoryTable');
        var $rowElement;
        var $cellElement;
        var index = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < categoryList.length; index++) {
            $rowElement = $('<tr></tr>');
            $cellElement = $('<td></td>', { text: categoryList[index].CategoryName });
            $rowElement.append($cellElement);
            $cellElement = $('<td></td>', { text: categoryList[index].CategoryId });
            $rowElement.append($cellElement);
            $courseTableElement.append($rowElement);


        }
    });

</script>
```

```
    public List<Category> getAllCategory(string inUserId)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>();
        string sqlText = "";
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            cn.ConnectionString =
          ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = cn; //setup the 
                cn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    sqlText = "SELECT CategoryId,CategoryName,CreatedBy,CreatedAt,UpdatedBy,UpdatedAt " +
              " FROM Category ";
                    cmd.CommandText = sqlText;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@inCurrentUserId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = inUserId;


                    da.Fill(ds, "CategoryData");
                    cmd.CommandText = sqlText;
                }//using SqlDataAdapter da
                cn.Close();

            }//using SQLCommand cmd
        }//using SQLConnection cn

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["CategoryData"].Rows)
        {

            Category category = new Category();
            category.CategoryId = Int32.Parse(dr["CategoryId"].ToString());
            category.CategoryName = dr["CategoryName"].ToString();
            category.CreatedBy = dr["CreatedBy"].ToString();
            category.CreatedAt = DateTime.Parse(dr["CreatedAt"].ToString());
            category.UpdatedBy = dr["UpdatedBy"].ToString();
            category.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Parse(dr["UpdatedAt"].ToString());
            categoryList.Add(category);
        }


        return categoryList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make an ajax request to your server and grab that data. I'm making a couple of assumptions.

1. That getAllCategory is accessible to the frontend via webapi or something of the sort.
2. That getAllCategory will return proper json.

   ```
     function getDataFromServer(url, callback){
         var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.open("get",url);
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readystate === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
               //data was retrieved successfully. 
               callback(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response));
            }
         }
         xmlhttp.send();
     }

     $(document).ready(function () {
       //the path to action must include the id in querystring
       var url = 'path_to_action'
       getDataFromServer(url, function(data){
          var courseTableElement = $('#categoryTable');
          for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
             var row = $('<tr></tr>');
             var cell1 = $('<td></td>, { text: data[i].CategoryName } );
             var cell2 = $('<td></td>, { text: data[i].CategoryId } );
             row.append(cell1);
             row.append(cell2);
             courseTableElement.append(row);
          }
       }
     });
   ```